# Error on retrieving posts id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From a WordPress account I am displaying the titles of the posts, if you click on any of the titles, you will be redirected to a new view in order to check the entire post.

here the html

```
  <a ng-href="#/tabs/news/{{post.ID}}">
    <h2 ng-bind-html="post.title"></h2>
  </a>
```

and here the view to see the full post

```
<h3>{{:: post.content}}</h3>
```

that's all I have in that view.

look at the code

```
.state('tabs.news', {
    url: '/news',
    views: {
      'tab-news': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-news.html',
        controller: 'NewsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

.state('tabs.post-detail', {
  url: '/news/:postId',
  views: {
    'tab-news': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-post-detail.html',
      controller: 'PostDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

`/news` is the main view where you are able to see the titles, and `'/news/:postId`is the view where you see the entire post

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, FreshlyPressed) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
  }
});
```

the service

```
.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function($scope) {
      $scope.posts = [];
      $http.jsonp('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function(result) {
          $scope.posts = result.posts;
        });
    },

    get: function(postId, $scope) {
      console.log(postId);
      console.log($scope.posts);
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.posts.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.posts[i].id === parseInt(postId)) {
          return $scope.posts[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
})
```

and the controller for `/news/:postId`

```
.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, FreshlyPressed) {
  $scope.post = FreshlyPressed.get($stateParams.postId, $scope);
});
```

as I have it so far I am getting `posts`as Undefined and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

what am I doing wrong ?

here is what I am getting from the result object

```
{
    date_range: {
        newest: "2015-05-09T20:02:01+00:00",
        oldest: "2015-05-06T20:02:02+00:00"
    },
    number: 10,
    posts: [{
        ID: 706,
        site_ID: 42659653,
        author: {
            ID: 42088694,
            login: "oliviaacole",
            email: false,
            name: "oliviaacole",
            nice_name: "oliviaacole",
            URL: "http://oliviaacole.wordpress.com",
            avatar_URL: "https://1.gravatar.com/avatar/adea7829a98ebdba180a6ff6ce1beeef?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG",
            profile_URL: "http://en.gravatar.com/oliviaacole",
            site_ID: 42659653
        },
        date: "2014-12-03T18:07:51-06:00",
        modified: "2015-04-30T08:14:23-05:00",
        title: "White Rage, the Hunger Games, and the Lack of Justice for Eric Garner",
        URL: "https://oliviaacole.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/white-rage-the-hunger-games-and-the-lack-of-justice-for-eric-garner/",
        short_URL: "http://wp.me/p2SZIV-bo",
        content: "<p><a href="
        https: //oliviaacole.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/peacekeeper.jpg"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-707" src="https://oliviaacole.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/peacekeeper.jpg?w=494&#038;h=214" alt="eric garner" width="494" height="214" /></a></p> <p>Today, like too many days, I am angry. Today a <a </p> ",
        excerpt: "<p>Today, like too many days, I am angry. Today a grand jury voted not to bring criminal charges against the white officer who killed Eric Garner, father of six, with a chokehold. The killing is on video, which many people hoped would mean an indictment and, eventually, a conviction. Not so. Today, America tells us [&hellip;]</p> ",
        slug: "white-rage-the-hunger-games-and-the-lack-of-justice-for-eric-garner",
        guid: "http://oliviaacole.wordpress.com/?p=706",
        status: "publish",
        sticky: false,
        password: "",
        parent: false,
        type: "post",
        comments_open: true,
        pings_open: true,
        likes_enabled: true,
        sharing_enabled: true,
        comment_count: 40,
        like_count: 74,
        i_like: 0,
        is_reblogged: 0,
        is_following: 0,
        global_ID: "7235f7d1c1e185bcc0fbd19cb0b3b088",
        featured_image: "",
        post_thumbnail: null,
        format: "standard",
        geo: false,
        menu_order: 0,
        publicize_URLs: [],
        tags: {
```

Comment: take a look at the data structure of "result" - the "posts" data you are expecting is probably sitting on a node within results - maybe on "d" or "value" or some other such identifier...

Comment: ok - I'd expect there to be more structure before '"date_range": {...' even if it's just an opening curly brace, but please don't just give us that curly brace; give us everything that is returned!

Comment: @lukkea see it again

Comment: the formatting is all wrong on what you just added and that is data from the end - not really what we need to see!  I would expect there to be something *before* "date_range" right at the start of the data; an opening curly brace, at a minimum, but for my gut feeling to be right there will be something more before the opening curly brace...

Comment: @lukkea https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed/ that is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77443/discussion-between-lukkea-and-nietzscheprogrammer).

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass scope to a service, instead return the `$http` promise from the service

Modified service method

```
getBlogs: function() {

 return $http.jsonp('https://public....essed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
         .error(function(){ alert('oops...error');});
 }
```

Controller

```
 FreshlyPressed.getBlogs().success(function(result){
      console.log(result);//have a peak at response in console
      $scope.posts = result.posts;
 });
```

Comment: what other changes do I need to do ? I am not getting errors, but I can't see the titles in my screen.

Comment: depends how your `ng-repeat` looks

Comment: ```ng-repeat="post in posts"```

Comment: good trick in view is `<pre>{{post|json}}</pre>` can see what any object looks like printed to json and see if it is structured as expected. bit ugly when there's whole wordpress posts involved but in general very helpful

Comment: are there repeating elements showing up? IS code inside `$scope.doRefresh` and you never called that method? Also browsers have angular scope inspection tool add-ons for dev tools which are very helpful

Comment: as I had it before everything was fine, the only issue was that I can't access to the entire post by the post id. Now, I can't see anything in the main view ```news```

Comment: your `get()` in service is all convoluted too because of $scope that doesn't exist in service. Rather than unwind that would just make request with specific post id to api for simplicity and learn how to work with services first

Comment: did not get you, sorry.

Comment: In your single post view use postid routeparam to get that individual post from api. Can use `resolve` in the routing to return the api call request promise

Comment: are you still there ? look at this, I just did it, try clicking in the title of the news and then see the console. There is all my code regarding my issue http://jsbin.com/libotacoxu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: new controller...new scope . Can't do what you are doing passing scope to service. In this case it's a different scope

Comment: so, what should I do ? I thought it was the right way.

Comment: simplest right now...is add another service mehtod ...`getBlogById(id)` ...then in single controller call that. API should be easy to figure out params for a single post. Get the ID from `$routeParams`